# How to join together 2 tibbles into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr

I have a dataset (shown below) and have written a bunch of R code to perform 2 main functions: give me the fold change for each of my treatments over control, across all parameters; and to give me the p values for all treatments against control, across all parameters. This has generated 2 tibbles via the summarise function. The fold change tibble is 12x5 and the p.value tibble is 10x5.

I need to do two things: 
1. remove two rows from the fold change tibble to make it 10x5
2. to bind the two tibbles (now, both 10x5) together.

I tried to filter out my 2 control treatments from the fold change tibble and then cbind the two together, but I keep getting errors.

Heres the data, all of it has been averaged.

```
 chemistry  rate Digital biomass[mm^3] greenness average[] Height [mm]
1    Control     0             135484.07           0.2167113    86.27765
2    Flavone 0.001             135090.45           0.2025817    81.21167
3    Flavone  0.01             144547.00           0.2078100    82.85367
4    Flavone   0.1             145807.70           0.2043300    84.96300
5    Flavone     1             110408.18           0.1949033    81.48700
6    Flavone    10              53585.55           0.1850100    69.78533
7      SA3F2 0.001             158966.67           0.2051417    85.33000
8      SA3F2  0.01             167762.00           0.2113683    88.58500
9      SA3F2   0.1             159897.50           0.2021017    86.60617
10     SA3F2     1             181713.50           0.1995667    85.57567
11     SA3F2    10             136530.00           0.1964467    81.84200
```

Here is the code that calculates fold change:

```
  fold.change <- cleaned.averagedreps.nona %>%
    group_by(chemistry) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(3:5), ~./.[rate == '0'])
```

Here is the code that calculates p.values. This is done in a similar data set as the one shown above, but with reps so that the t.test can compute.

```
#add colums for p values
  #remove NA
cleaned.repdata.nona <- na.omit(cleaned.repdata)
  #seperate control
control <- cleaned.repdata.nona %>%
  filter(cleaned.repdata.nona$rate == "0")

  #process p values
broad.pvalues <- cleaned.repdata.nona %>%
  group_by(chemistry, rate) %>%
  filter(chemistry != "Control") %>%
  summarise("biomass.p" = t.test(`Digital biomass[mm^3]`, control$`Digital biomass[mm^3]`)$p.value,
            "greenness.p" = t.test(`greenness average[]`, control$`greenness average[]`)$p.value,
            "height.p" = t.test(`Height [mm]`, control$`Height [mm]`)$p.value)
```

Here is what I wrote to stick my two tibbles together and the errors that came up:

```
#make both dataframes the same size (i.e. remove control rows in fold change)
> fold.change <- filter_at(fold.change, all.vars(!(fold.change$rate == "Control")))
Error: `.predicate` has no matching columns
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
> final <- cbind(fold.change, broad.pvalues)
Error: Argument 2 must be length 12, not 10
```

Let me know if y'all have any solutions. I'm hoping to turn this tibble into a df so its less finicky and easier to output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be `all_vars` instead of `all.vars` also the column names should be specified within `vars`

```
library(dplyr)
filter_at(fold.change, vars(rate), all_vars(!(. == "Control")))
```

If there is only single column, just use `filter`

```
fold.change %>%
         filter(rate != 'Control')
```

---

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars`,

```
mtcars %>%
       filter_at(vars(mpg, drat, wt), all_vars(. > 3))
```

returns the rows where 'mpg', 'drat', 'wt' have all values greater than 3 in a row